# how to add compile for QtCreator on Fedora?

Tags: gcc, qt-creator, qt5.5

Qt Creator Kits Option
[image: Qt Creator Kits Option]

Qt Creator Compilers
[image: Qt Creator Compilers]

Qt Versions: 5.5 x86.i have added QTDIR to PATH.Qt Creator cannot detect GCC?

Comment: As I see in the image of the compiler section: your compiler is 64bit, but your version of Qt is 32bits, so you can not add it.

Comment: @eyllanesc  but my OS is i386 fedora.

Comment: review the last section of ABI